# Selection in edit mode not highlighted yellow

Tags: modeling, mesh, particles, edit-mode, selection-tools

In edit mode, when I select vertices, edges or faces, I can move and edit the selection as usual, but it isn't highlighted yellow. The problem apparently occured after implementing "empty hair" curve. Since then, the object is called "*object* : basis" in the top left corner. Usually, it's named without the basis. Removing the empty hair didn't fix the issue. Viewport overlays are on and "edges" and "faces" are checked. How can I make the selection highlighted again? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Has the overlay disappeared on all objects, even those not associated with the hair?  Perhaaps share a representative file on https://blend-exchange.com/ .

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution after much searching. I had to deactivate "Add Rest Position" in Shape keys.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial, stand on their own, and thoroughly explain the solution and required steps. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can, [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and how it works, perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating some steps and final result. See [How to write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), otherwise it may be converted to a comment.